# problem on determinant as a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

For $V = (V_1,V_2 )\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $W = (W_1,W_2 )\in\mathbb{R}^2$ ,
Consider the determinant map
$$\det :\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$$ defined by
$$\det(V,W) = V_1W_2 -V_2W_1$$

Then the derivative of the determinant map at $(V,W)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ evaluated on $(H, K )\in\mathbb{R}^2 \times\mathbb{R}^2$ is:

1. $\det (H,W) + \det(V, K )$
2. $\det (H, K )$
3. $\det (H,V ) + \det(W, K )$
4. $\det (V,W) + \det(K,W)$

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Just write down $\det(V+ H, W+K) - \det(V,W)$ and toss away the higher order term.

Comment: Hint: Multilinear maps satisfy the product rule.

Comment: This is your fourth question that appears to be copied from somewhere. Please cite your sources, tell us whether a question is homework, and explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: In particular, please see how you can improve your problem based on advice given [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a continuous bi-linear map(in general multilinear) $ f: E_1 \times E_2 \rightarrow F $ , where $ E_1, E_2,F $ are Banach spaces, then given

$ v_1 \in E_1 $ and $ v_2 \in E_2 $ ,

$ Df(v_1, v_2)(h_1,h_2) = f(v_1, h_2) +f(h_1, v_2) $ .

This follows from the definition of Frechet derivative and the expression therein. Martini has already written it down explicitly.